# My thumbnails in a row are not side by side (Instead stacking on top of each other)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I want to do what I thought was pretty basic, have a row of 6 thumbnails that would stack to two rows of 3 thumbnails on XS displays. But for some reason all of my thumbnails stack in two columns. I am sure I am missing something obvious here.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" style="width:30%">
      <img src="img/cottagefront.png" alt="...">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" style="width:30%">
      <img src="img/cottagekitchen.png" alt="...">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" style="width:30%">
      <img src="img/backbonestateparktrail.jpg" alt="...">
    </a>

  </div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" style="width:30%">
      <img src="img/cottagebed.png" alt="...">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" style="width:30%">
      <img src="img/backbonestatepark.jpg" alt="...">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" style="width:30%">
      <img src="img/cottageliving.png" alt="...">
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

This looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWp19.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

`img` by default act as block level element and occupy the full width space. So while in `xs` screen size, it occupies 100% of the width while in `md` screen size mode, it just occupies 50% of width.

Also, anchor tags do not take width values. You will need to include `display: block` before specifying width. Fixing either one of the problems can lead up to the solution.

**Solution:**

You need to change your markup. Wrap the thumbnails inside a grid class instead of inline style.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```